# Shell Script With sed and Random number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

How to make a shell script that receives one or more text files and removes from them whitespaces and blanklines. After that new files will have a random 2-digit number in front of them.
For example `File1.txt` generates `File1_56.txt`

Tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$*"; do
sed -e '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' $* >> "$*_$$.txt"
done
```

But when I give 2 files as input script merges them into one single file, when I want for each file a separate one.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$@"; do
    sed -e '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' "$file" >> "${file%.txt}_$$.txt"
done
```

#### Notes

1. To loop over each argument without word splitting or other hazards, use `for file in "$@"` not `for file in "$*"`
2. To run the sed command on one file instead of all, specify `"$file"` as the file, not `$*`.
3. To save the output to the correct file, use `"${file%.txt}_$$.txt"` where `${file%.txt}` is an example of *suffix removal*: it removes the final `.txt` from the file name.
4. `$$` is the process ID.  The title says mentions a "random" number.  If you want a random number, replace `$$` with `$RANDOM`.